# Postfix 3.1.0 terminates on signal 15 every 2 Minutes on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, postfix-mta, terminate

Heyas,

we have a web and email server running since many years on Ubuntu 15.10 with Postfix, Dovecot, Amavis, Spamassassin and Clamav. Everything ran fine since many years.

Today in the morning I updated this server to Ubuntu 16.04 and thus, Postfix now is version 3.1.0. Still everything is running fine except one small problem:

**The postfix master process terminates itself on signal 15 every two minutes.**

All email accounts are there, relay is not possible, emails can be sent and received... everything is fine, except that Postfix terminates every two minutes.

This is the postconf output for the main configuration:

https://pastebin.com/3Fv0syXK

This is the postconf -M output:

https://pastebin.com/7YeQEsFC

This is the syslog output... there is ***nothing related before*** these lines:

https://pastebin.com/bi0MXAQN

**I really hope, someone can help me with that....**

I've written a small cron script that runs once a minute, that restarts postfix when it gets terminated... but this is no solution.

---

since "links to pastebin must be accompanied by code"
here's the cron script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..20}; do
    mpid=$(pidof master)
    time=$(date +%H:%M:%S)
    echo "Checking at ${time}..." >> /root/postfix.log
    if [[ "${mpid}" = "" ]]; then
        echo "Restarting postfix..." >> /root/postfix.log
        service postfix restart
    fi
    sleep 3
done
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I have found the solution.
The problem was, that the monitoring application "monit" tried to restart postfix when swap usage reaches > 25%. Since there was a problem in the monit configuration, it only was able to stop postfix and not to restart it.

I've fixed the monit configuration, increased the maximum swap usage in /etc/monit/monitrc, restarted monit and since then Postfix runs and runs and runs, without pronlems.